# ActionBar tabs not working with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"

Tags: android

I want my application with no title bar, but there is an activity which has two swipe tabs given below

```
public class APlus_Post extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ActionBar actionBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        actionBar = getActionBar(); 
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab(); //First Tab
        tab1.setText("QAs Wall");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab(); //Second Tab
        tab2.setText("Track Companies");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {

    }

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

         Fragment fragment=null;

         if(arg0==0){
             fragment=new APlus_PostFragment1();
         }
         if(arg0==1){
             fragment=new APlus_PostFragment2();
         }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }


}
```

with layout associated post.xml given below

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Whenever i run these above code with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` (in AndroidMenifesto.xml) it works fine, but when i use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"` it doesn't work.

I want those swipe tabs on action bar but not the title bar in any activity of my application.

Comment: I got a solution that is to use this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: Use this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) inside onCreate() method of each and every activity except one which has swipe tabs. We can use .setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) and .setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) for that particular activity. Other solutions are also appreciable.

Comment: Could you show me some log information about your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Could you add a little more details about your solution?